# class KafkaServerStartable not supported from Kafka v 2.8

Tags: apache-kafka

I was using Kafka v2.7 and upgrading to Kafka 3.0.0.

`class KafkaServerStartable` has been removed from v2.8.1.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you trying to run an embedded broker for a test? If so, the general recommendation would be to use testcontainers, if possible https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/

Comment: No, not for a test, bumping up the pom

Comment: But your actual code shouldn't depend on the Kafka server itself unless you are running an integration test. In other words, remove your dependencies that are like `kafka_2.xx` and use `kafka-clients` or `kafka-streams` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache Kafka 2.8.1 and later versions, the KafkaServerStartable class has been removed and replaced with the KafkaServer class. The KafkaServer class provides similar functionality to KafkaServerStartable, but with a different API.

Here is an example of how you can start a Kafka server using the KafkaServer class in Kafka 3.0.0:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Time;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils;
import org.apache.kafka.server.KafkaConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.server.KafkaServer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaServerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
        props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.LOG_DIR_CONFIG, new File("/tmp/kafka-logs").getAbsolutePath());
        KafkaConfig config = new KafkaConfig(props);
        KafkaServer server = new KafkaServer(config, Time.SYSTEM, "kafka-server");
        server.startup();
        // do something with the server
        server.shutdown();
        server.awaitShutdown();
    }
}
```

his example starts a Kafka server with default configuration values and listens on the default port (9092). You can customize the configuration by setting additional properties in the props object.

Note that the KafkaServer class is part of the kafka-server module, so you will need to include this dependency in your project to use it. You can add the following dependency to your Maven pom.xml file to include the kafka-server module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

it's still working with 2.4.0 version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The question is more specifically about the new version